# MongoDB map-reduce slow and runs out of memory

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I would like to use MongoDB as the backend for the analytics system I am building.
One of the main advantages of using MongoDB is the built-in map reduce.
Since we are at "medium data" scale, we do not yet need the overhead of Hadoop.

For testing purposes I insert 50 million rows of the type

```
{
 user_id: xxxx,
 thing_id:xxxx,
 time: xxx
}
```

With an index on user_id on an EC2 Large Instance. Its a Single instance mongodb (not sharded).

```
db.user_thing_like.find({user_id: 37104857})
```

takes less than a second.

However a mapreduce where I wanted to count the number of user entries took all night and returned with an out of memory error, either I must be doing something stupid or mongo db is not right tool for what I want to do.

I am new to Mongo DB and would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

ERROR :

```
Tue Aug  9 13:15:58 uncaught exception: map reduce failed:{
        "assertion" : "invoke failed: JS Error: out of memory nofile_b:2",
        "assertionCode" : 9004,
        "errmsg" : "db assertion failure",
        "ok" : 0
}
```

MAPREDUCE QUERY:

```
db.user_thing_like.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: "tmp_test"}, {query: {"user_id" : 37104857 }});
```

MAP AND REDUCE:

```
map = function () {
    for (var key in this) {
        emit(key.user_id, {count: 1});
    }
};

reduce = function (key, emits) {
    total = 0;
    for (var i in emits) {
        total += emits[i].count;
    }
    return {"count": total};
}
```

--- UPDATE ---

I realized that the mapreduce was not considering my query filter, in the syntax I used.

Here is the correct mapreduce query.

```
db.runCommand({mapreduce: "user_thing_like", map: map, reduce: reduce, out: "tmp_test", query: {"user_id" : 37104857 }});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
map = function () {
        emit(this.user_id, {count: 1});
    }
};
```

Also, try to specify `user_id` as sort key for MapReduce, from the manual:

```
sort : <sorts the input objects using this key. Useful for optimization, like sorting by the emit key for fewer reduces>]
```

Comment: Solved. db.runCommand({mapreduce: "user_thing_like", map: map, reduce: reduce, out: "tmp_test", query: {"user_id" : 37104857 }});

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the mapreduce was not considering my query filter, in the syntax I used.

Here is the correct mapreduce query.

```
db.runCommand({mapreduce: "user_thing_like", map: map, reduce: reduce, out: "tmp_test", query: {"user_id" : 37104857 }});
```

Comment: This kind of comment should be included in the original question, not provided as an answer to the question.  I moved these comments into the question for you.